# Message queue - WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, keypress

the message queue is present in any type of program or Unix is present only in programs written in Windows interface?

For example this programm:

```
int main()
{
    short int n;
    while(1)
    {
        if (n = GetKeyState(VK_UP))
        {   
            cout << n;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << n;
        }

    Sleep(150);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

have or not the message queue? If yes, the GetKeyState function retrieves the keyboard messages from the message queue?

Comment: Why did you ask your previous question and then ignore the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must call `PeekMessage` or `GetMessage` to make `GetKeyState` return new values, for further reading look here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/30/272262.aspx

and here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you dont want message loop use `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Answer (score 0):

`GetKeyState` is a Windows function that interacts closely with the Windows message queue. The function does not exist in Unix.

As I explained in your previous question, `GetKeyState` provides information about the key state associated with the most recently retrieved message. Since your console application does not have a message queue, and is not pumping messages, `GetKeyState` yields no useful information.

Again, as explained in your previous question, you use `GetAsyncKeyState` to obtain information about the state *at the instant that the API call is made*.

Finally, again repeating statements from your earlier question, test for a key being pressed by checking for a negative return value. For instance:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) < 0)
    ....
```

My most important advice to you is that when you ask a question here on Stack Overflow, you read the answers! If you don't understand them, leave comments asking for clarification.